# Mysql update date year

Tags: mysql, sql

In table have row datetime format `2013-01-01 01:01:01` I want update, date row and chenge all years from `2013` to `2012`

My `SQL UPDATE`tickets`SET YEAR(`t_date`) = 2012 WHERE YEAR(`t_date`) = 2013`

But this not work , what is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT date_Add(t_date - INTERVAL 1 YEAR), t_date
FROM your TableName where year(T_Date) =2013

Update yourTableName set t_date= date_Add(t_date-Interval 1) YEAR WHERE year(T_DATE) = 2013
```

You're method isn't working because your syntax is incorrect.  Check [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

exact [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate)

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong is that `YEAR(t_date)` is the result of a function and you cannot update the result of a function.

You can do

```
update tickets
   set t_date = date_add(t_date, interval -1 year)
 where year(t_date) = 2013
```